# How come code re-usability is a benefit of Bottom-Up software development?

Tags: software-engineering, object-oriented

> Re-usability of code is one of the main benefits of the bottom-up approach
> ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-down_and_bottom-up_design#Software_development))

I can't quite figure out how bottom-up approach enables code re-usability. I am aware that Object Oriented Programming is bottom-up approach and it has features such as inheritance that enable code re-usability. But I cannot connect bottom-up with code re-usability intuitively.

Comment: Wikipedia immediately follows that statement with a citation.  Have you tried reading it to see what it says?

Comment: Actually I couldn't find the source from that link. Also I would like to get a simple but understandable answer.